# How to generate forest plot for Cronbach's Alpha & ICC (metafor)?

Tags: r, reliability, metafor

I'm trying to create a forest plot in metafor for pooled reliability estimates (Cronbach's Alpha and ICC) for a systematic review we've done. I want to do the same as the authors have in the image I've pasted (which comes from here: https://doi.org/10.1177/1071100718816953). i.e.: we'd like to recreate these sorts of analyses using our data.
I can't find a tutorial or example code for this despite exhausting the search engine here and google, nor can I figure out from the help which doesn't seem to touch on this (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/metafor/versions/1.9-9/topics/escalc or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metafor/metafor.pdf).
I've emailed the corresponding author who suggested we read: https://www.um.es/metaanalysis/pdf/5049.pdf, but this hasn't helped (nothing about R or the steps involved in creating the analyses/plots in there).
 
Can anyone point me in the direction of some help for the steps required to do this? 
Here's the image:

[image: Figure displaying Forest plot of pooled reliability measures]

Edit: clarified we were trying to do our own analysis, not recreate someone else's, & added the corresponding author's reply

Comment: Doesn't appear like the supplementary materials in the article provide data, do you have the data?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding - we are looking to do the same sort of analyses on our own data, but can't figure out how to do this using metafor. If possible does anyone know of a tutorial or example code which goes through the process of creating the Forest plots of reliability as in the example above (so we can do the same with our data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for Cronbach's alpha, using the transformation by Bonett (2002) before analyzing the alpha values (not sure what the authors used).

```
library(metafor)
dat <- dat.bonett2010
res <- rma(measure="ABT", ai=ai, mi=mi, ni=ni, data=dat)
forest(res, slab=dat$source, header=TRUE, atransf=transf.iabt, refline=coef(res))
```

[image: forest plot]

Adjust as needed. See `help(forest.rma)` (or [here](https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.rma.html)) for details on what can be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang - final question, what measure should be used when pooling an ICC? From the escalc help files it's not clear: Partial and Semi-Partial Correlations ... The options for the measure argument are then:

"PCOR" for the partial correlation coefficient.

"ZPCOR" for Fisher's r-to-z transformed partial correlation coefficient.

"SPCOR" for the semi-partial correlation coefficient.

Comment: An ICC is not a partial or semi-partial correlation. There is no functionality in `escalc()` for dealing with ICCs.

Comment: Thanks again - it looks like there's no clear method to pool ICC's according to: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811919307487 & they recommend against Fisher Z transforming as the results of the meta analysis can't be interpreted. I can't figure out what the authors in  https://doi.org/10.1177/1071100718816953 did to get their results that were the original motivation here (they haven't been helpful in emails). If I've missed a method, please let me know. If I figure this out, I'll post a reply here.